# Insert N Blank Rows to R Data Frame Using Value in a Column

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have a data frame:

```
Var_1 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
Var_2 = c(0,1,0,2,1,0,0,1)
DF = data.frame(Var_1,Var_2)
print(DF)

 Var_1 Var_2
1     A     0
2     B     1
3     C     0
4     D     2
5     E     1
6     F     0
7     G     0
8     H     1
```

I need to insert **N** blank rows filled with NA into the data frame, using the value found in **Var_2** to determine **N**.  These new rows should be inserted immediately after the **Var_2** value is >=1.  So I'd like my data frame to look like this:

```
print(DF)

 Var_1 Var_2
1      A     0
2      B     1
3   <NA>    NA
4      C     0
5      D     2
6   <NA>    NA
7   <NA>    NA
8      E     0
9      F     0
10     G     0
11     H     1
12  <NA>    NA
```

I'm pretty stuck with this, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequences and subsetting to the rescue.
Duplicating each row by `Var_2 + 1` generates `Var_2` extra rows when the value is `> 0` and maintains the row when the value `== 0`
Then you can use the `duplicated` `TRUE/FALSE` on the sequence to replace only the additional rows with `NA`.

```
s <- rep(sequence(nrow(DF)), DF$Var_2 + 1)
DFnew <- DF[s,]
DFnew[duplicated(s),] <- NA
DFnew
#    Var_1 Var_2
#1       A     0
#2       B     1
#2.1  <NA>    NA
#3       C     0
#4       D     2
#4.1  <NA>    NA
#4.2  <NA>    NA
#5       E     1
#5.1  <NA>    NA
#6       F     0
#7       G     0
#8       H     1
#8.1  <NA>    NA
```

This should also be pretty quick on all but the most massive datasets.

```
# 800K records
DF <- DF[rep(1:8,1e5),]
system.time({
  s <- rep(sequence(nrow(DF)), DF$Var_2 + 1)
  DFnew <- DF[s,]
  DFnew[duplicated(s),] <- NA
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.600   0.000   0.601
```

Comment: Just realized, the logic of my answer is similar to yours but yours is in base.

Comment: @RonakShah - the more the merrier. Feel like doing a benchmark?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem:

```r
ind <- which(DF$Var_2 > 0)
ind
# [1] 2 4 5 8
starts <- 1L + unique(c(0L, head(ind, n = -1)))
stops <- unique(c(ind, nrow(DF))) # in case the last !0 is not on bottom row
starts
# [1] 1 3 5 6
stops
# [1] 2 4 5 8
DFaug_list <- Map(
  function(a, b) rbind(DF[a:b,], DF[b,][rep(NA, DF$Var_2[b]), ]),
  starts, stops)
```

We now have a list of frames:

```r
str(DFaug_list)
# List of 4
#  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ Var_1: Factor w/ 8 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 NA
#   ..$ Var_2: int [1:3] 0 1 NA
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ Var_1: Factor w/ 8 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 3 4 NA NA
#   ..$ Var_2: int [1:4] 0 2 NA NA
#  $ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ Var_1: Factor w/ 8 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 5 NA
#   ..$ Var_2: int [1:2] 1 NA
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ Var_1: Factor w/ 8 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 6 7 8 NA
#   ..$ Var_2: int [1:4] 0 0 1 NA
```

and all we have to do to combine them is a trick with `do.call` or use functions from either of the `data.table` or `dplyr` packages:

```r
DFaug <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, DFaug_list)
DFaug
#      Var_1 Var_2
# 1        A     0
# 2        B     1
# NA    <NA>    NA
# 3        C     0
# 4        D     2
# NA1   <NA>    NA
# NA.1  <NA>    NA
# 5        E     1
# NA2   <NA>    NA
# 6        F     0
# 7        G     0
# 8        H     1
# NA3   <NA>    NA
DFaug <- data.table::rbindlist(DFaug_list)
DFaug <- dplyr::bind_rows(DFaug_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could repeat each row `Var_2` times and replace `duplicated` rows with `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 <- DF %>% mutate(Var_3 = Var_2 + 1, row = row_number()) %>% 
             tidyr::uncount(Var_3)
DF1[duplicated(DF1$row), ] <- NA
DF1$row <- NULL

#    Var_1 Var_2
#1       A     0
#2       B     1
#2.1  <NA>    NA
#3       C     0
#4       D     2
#4.1  <NA>    NA
#4.2  <NA>    NA
#5       E     1
#5.1  <NA>    NA
#6       F     0
#7       G     0
#8       H     1
#8.1  <NA>    NA
```

Comment: Not that it happens in the current example, but I think this might also fall over if you happen to have duplicated rows in the source data in multiple places. Using a row counter avoids that I think.